# Portal login on Single sign on

Tags: single-sign-on

I configured Single sign-on for my sandbox and then tested with standard user. Login by a standards user is successful. But for a portal user failed.

I read that it is required to provide with Portal Id to Identity Provider when setting up with Identity Provider. But Salesforce Identity Provider was setup by itself when creating the My Domain.

Is there a way Portal ID can be provided to the Identity Provider or someone know about more on Portal login on Single Sign-On?

Thanks in advance for any help